# js not working in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

i am trying to change text of label and textbox text on checkbox clicked.

i have noticed that asp.net fully support js .

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#chkhtml').change(function () {

            $('#Text1').prop("disabled", !$(this).is(':checked'));



            document.getElementById('#Text1').innerHTML = 'newtext';

            document.getElementById('#<%=rollLbl.ClientID %>').innerHTML = 'your text goes here';
            document.getElementById('#testlbl').innerHTML = 'newtext';

        });


    });
</script>
```

However it only enable or disable text box but don't change text of any label or text box.

i have already tried .value .content  etc but none of these work plzzz plzz help me .

Comment: Please share HTML.

Comment: <input name="secondPart_txt" class="form-control logpadding" type="number" disabled="" id="Text1" />

Comment: Check my updated code.

Comment: To say that "ASP.NET supports JS" is silly. Browsers run HTML, JavaScript, CSS etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mixed up jQuery and Javascript:

> jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#chkhtml').change(function() {
            $('#Text1').prop("disabled", !$(this).is(':checked'));
            $('#Text1').val('newtext');
            $('#<%=rollLbl.ClientID %>').html('your text goes here');
            $('#testlbl').html('newtext');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Please amend below changes in your code, if you want to keep original.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#chkhtml').change(function() {
            $('#Text1').prop("disabled", !$(this).is(':checked'));
            document.getElementById('Text1').value = 'newtext';
            document.getElementById('<%=rollLbl.ClientID %>').innerHTML = 'your text goes here';
            document.getElementById('testlbl').innerHTML = 'newtext';
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: F.Y.I. You have also mixed both of them. *Javascript* section have jQuery code still like DOM `ready`, `change` event handler and `prop` method.

Comment: @palaѕн: Agreed. Better if I just keep jQuery section for time being.Will provide pure javascript code to OP once I have enough time.

Comment: thanks .... but still its not working on textbox ... i want to mention that textbox is disabled and only enable by checkbox

Comment: In case you are using asp text box then id would be not just like `Text1`, you might need to use `<%=Text1.ClientID %>` for that. Please post the html part also that you are using in OP.

Comment: actually textbox is html element  for testing i am using html input type                  Second Part Roll No
                            <input name="secondPart_txt" class="form-control logpadding" type="number" disabled="" id="Text1" />

Comment: Thanks alot now i understand jquery and js plain  my last issue is to retrieve old text on uncheck checkbox.   bundle of thanks in advance.

Comment: Pleasure helping you out :) If my answer solved your problem, click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer, this would help me in building good reputation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
document.getElementById('#Text1')
```

to

```
document.getElementById('Text1')
```

And the rest of such calls too. `getElementById` accepts an ID, not a selector.

Comment: its only work for label but not working for text box ... and value changes only for once how we can retrieve old value of label or text

Answer (score 0):

you may try in jquery

```
$('#Text1').html('newtext');
$('#<%=rollLbl.ClientID %>').html('your text goes here');
```

or in plain javascript

```
document.getElementById('Text1').innerHTML = 'newtext';
document.getElementById('<%=rollLbl.ClientID %>').innerHTML = 'your text goes here';
```

you need to pass only the id of the element to `getelementById()`. but jquery uses css query selector so `#name` means it is an id and `.name` means it is a class